# How to read txt files with those languages which is read from right to left with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

Here is a code that is reading a file for me. But each word of the file is reversed from the original text that I have put in `line.txt` file.

**line.txt**

```
  اور ایک
```

**test.py**

```
import re

f = open("line.txt",encoding="utf-8")
text = f.read()
print(text)
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure reading and printing works fine, at least as far as Python is concerned. Most probably it's your terminal emulator (console) that doesn't know about right-to-left scripts. Note: the directionality doesn't really matter for reading/writing text files – strings and text files are a simple sequence of characters in "reading order". The challenging part is _displaying_ them, ie. arranging the letters in 2D on a screen for humans to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this
https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper

or
`print(text[::-1])`

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to print the reversed text:

```
print(text[::-1])
```

Another solution is to use a bi-directional [library](https://pypi.org/project/python-bidi/) `python-bidi`

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

f = open("line.txt",encoding="utf-8")
text = f.read()
print(get_display(text))
```